# Execute every 10 rows

Tags: php, loops, counter

I need help. I need a loop that can execute some codes every 10 rows.
Suppose this is the scenario:

$rows = 15; // The row is for a generated report. I need to put a Thick Border, Horizontally every 10 rows.

This is the loop, and inside it I want another loop or any idea how can I execute some command every 10 rows assuming $row = 15, obviously the command should be executed once since the rows is only 15 and command will execute every 10 rows. Thanks everyone :)

```
         $rows = 15;              

         for($c=0;$c<$size3;$c++)
         {
           //Location I want to execute a command every 10 rows.
         }
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual loop?

Comment: please show the php code you are using for the  looping process

Comment: please specify some more code here.you have written just two lines of code.it's bit complicate to write the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try for loop for this

```
for($i = 1;$i <= 40;$i++) {
    if($i % 10 == 0) {
        // your horizontal code here
    } else {
        // non horizontal code here
    }
}
```

**Edit** Remember start the loop from `1` not from `0`. See codepad

[With 0](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jURC50)

[With 1](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ykHwnK)

Answer (score 0):

seems there is problem in $rows value, insted of adding condition on `$rows %10 ==0` you may try setting one counter $i in loop which will get increment for each row and then you can try adding condition on `$i %10 ==0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$startrow = 10 //10 if base 1 or 9 if base 0
$endrow = 15 //you said 15 so lets go with this 
for($row = $startrow; $row < $endrow; $row+=10)  
{  
  //do your thing here    
}
```

Since you only want to perform the action once every 10 rows, why not start at row 10, then go by increments of 10 instead of incrementing the row 1 by 1.

This should be more efficient since there will be no wasted loops given your circumstance, it also eliminates the need for checking if the row is divisible by 10.